# Recreate ODataQueryOptions from Request URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, routes, rabbitmq, odata

In my ASP.NET Core 3.1 project

I have a RabbitMQ consumer setup to fetch Database records. I am passing the OData based request URL with $expand, $filter, $count, $select as AllowedQueryOptions. I want to create an ODataQueryOptions object using just the Request URL and apply it to the DBSet I get from EF Core.

I am not able to achieve this outside of an OData Controller. How can I reuse the Query options for the same EDM model?

Comment: Well, just sample how I did that several years ago.  Check how it is suitable for you [here](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/blob/master/Tests/Linq/Microsoft/MicrosoftODataTests.cs#L138)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to access the Modelbuilder as the consumer code sits in a different project than the WebAPI one

Comment: Model builder is needed to build `IEdmModel`. Maybe you have access to Model?

Comment: I am using the IEdmModel in the WebApi project but that is different from the RabbitMq project which is different project and as far as I know we should build the models only once right?

Comment: I think yes. `ODataQueryContext` requires model.